# Merging many similar-looking projects in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have many separate projects in QGIS, each having the absolute same structure (layers etc.) because I made them all from one template project.
Each project is in its own folder, containing the qgz file and gpkg files for the layers.
Each one contains data for one separate "region".
Now I have the need to have one project containing all the data.

Is there any way to quickly merge them together, automatically joining layers with the same name?
I don't really want to open them all one by one and copy the content of each layer.
I feel like I can't be the first with that problem, although I found no helpful information so far in the Internet about that.
As a last resort, I can probably use a Python script to do that, but maybe there is an easier way that I am just not aware of?
I have seen some posts about project merging, but I want to specifically also merge layers with the same name together.

Comment: Try creating a model with load layer into project and run in batch mode, where you have to possibility to define rules form which folders/subfolders you want to load the layers.